# Why gcc -Og doesn't generate source code-line mapping?

Tags: gcc, gdb, mapping, symbol-table

I've got a simple .c file:

```
$ cat a.c
int i=0;
int j;
static int l=4;
void k(){}
void main(){
  k();
}
```

I tried to compile it with "-Og" to enable debug information. GCC man says

> -Og Optimize debugging experience.
>       -Og enables optimizations that do not interfere with debugging.

But when I use "gdb a.out" and try "list", it says:

> (gdb) l
>       No symbol table read. Please use "file" command.

Well this is so weird as out of my expectation, If I use `gcc a.c -g`, "list" is fine in gdb.
Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-Og is optimization switch. It enables any optimizations that don't interfere with debugging, but says nothing about debug information.

-g enables debug information (which is usually a separate non-code section).

So, use -Og -g or similar, to enable debug information and debug optimizations.

Your build with -g only enabled debug information, but left optimization at default level (which is completely disabled).

More information about debug options [in GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options), including this:
"If you are not using some other optimization option, consider using -Og (see Optimize Options) with -g. With no -O option at all, some compiler passes that collect information useful for debugging do not run at all, so that -Og may result in a better debugging experience."